# Worklight - getUserPref doesn't persist/load back?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I'm trying to persist some data for the user in this WL app using:

```
WL.Client.setUserPref('foo', 'bar');
```

and getting it back by using

```
WL.Client.getUserPref('key');
```

My target environment is Windows 8.1 with the latest Worklight Studio (6.2.0.01-20141015).

With a user logged in, I have tested this in:

- Preview Mode

  - Logged a user in
  - Set a user pref
  - Logged out
  - Closed window/tab
  - Opened, logged in again
  - Get back user pref (null)

Using the developer console in Chrome. I can see that there was a call out to save the preference when invoked, and confirmed that it had been set by calling getUserPref.

I've performed much the same test with Visual Studio 2013 by previewing the app and running the commands from the JS Console with the same results.

Is there something I'm missing here?

Answer (score 0):

I found that calling the connect after authenticating and before getting the preferences, i.e.:

```
WL.Cient.connect({onSuccess:successFunction, onFailure:failureFunction});
var myPref = WL.Client.getUserPref("myPref");
```

This should do the trick.

Comment: Interesting. So my current build auths but never explicitly calls connect(). Sucks that it resides solely on a server. Perhaps I'll build a JSONStore key-value store.