# How to implement "remember me"-like functionality?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I am developing an hybrid mobile application using ibm mobilefirst platform.

I am using the custom authentication module example to implement the login module. The problem here is when the user closes the application the app gets logged out.

Is there anyway that I can implement so that the user will not be logged out unless they opt to click on logout button. In simple I am trying to achieve something similar to Facebook remember me option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this (very rough idea):

As part of your authentication flow, if the user has passed the authentication - store in either localStorange or JSONStore a "token" that will basically state that the user has previously logged in. Also save in the server's database [using  userPrefs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26600974/worklight-getuserpref-doesnt-persist-load-back) something to validate the token.

1. Whenever the app launches, it will attempt to connect to the server. The environment will be protected with a securityTest so that the server will present a challenge - if a token exist it will attempt to verify it, if there is no token, a login form will display instead.
2. Assuming this is a first-time launch, if the login passed successfully then store a token in the device and store in the database its "public key"
3. The next time the app is launched the challenge will be presented again but this time, since we have a token - it will attempt to verify it. If verified - don't present the login screen, skip the rest of the authentication flow and display the secure content

Something like that...

Perhaps to create a 'better' user experience, on app launch also extend the splash screen duration while you're checking for the token, This can be done [using this API method](https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-0/advanced-client-side-development/common-ui-controls/#splashscreen).

On logout, clear the token from the device and server.

Comment: Hi thanks for your response. I will just try to implement this and will come back if I face any difficulty..

Comment: I tried to implement it like above.Now I am able to store the values locally and retrive it .on the app start if the local variable is there then i need the login process to happen in the background. when I call the custom authentication it is giving me the below error.            SRVE0190E: File not found: /apps/services/my_custom_auth_request_url
[ERROR   ] SRVE0293E: [Servlet Error]-[FWLSE0304E: Unhandled exception caught: